# How to rerender table with new columns and rows?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component with a Material-UI Table as a child component. I would like to allow the user to select which data they would like to display, press a button, and have it displayed in the Material-UI table.

The data is not necessarily of the same format each time (For example, the user might first wish to view a list of NFL players and their statistics. Later they want to view a list of games and their results.) Data is to be pulled from an API.

I have set up the Material-UI table component to accept arrays describing row data and column details for each dataset. The table then builds itself based on these parameters.

How can I accomplish this task? Currently I have the row and column data stored in state. The table components sets its props from the state. When the component is loaded the effect is triggered and the table is populated with some Player Data. I have a button with the onClick set to a function which will set the state with some new (and different data). However when I click the button my data disappears, and my headers remain as they were before clicking.

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Table from './SimpleTable';
import { getDummyPlayerData } from '../api_helper/api'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


const getColumnDetailsFromData = (data) => {
  var columns = [];

  Object.keys(rows[0]).forEach((key, index) => {
    columns.push({
      id: key,
      label: key,
      align: "right",
      component: "",
      scope: ""
    })
  })

  columns[0].align = "";
  columns[0].component = "th";
  columns[0].scope = "row";

  return columns;
}

export default function ParentDisplayTable() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [colDetails, setColDetails] = useState([]);
  const [uid, setUid] = useState(['player_id'])

  useEffect(() => {
    getDummyPlayerData().then(result => {
      setData(result);
      setColDetails(getColumnDetailsFromData(data));
    })
  }, []);

  const updateTable = (event) => {
    const rows = [
      {
        att1: "hello",
        att2: "goodbye"
      },
      {
        att1: "aloha",
        att2: "aloha"
      }
    ]

    const cols = getColumnDetailsFromData(rows);

    const key = "att1"

    setData(rows);
    setColDetails(cols);
    setUid(key);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        margin="normal"
        onClick={e => updateTable(e)}
      >
        Update Table
        </Button>
        
      <Table
        columns={colDetails}
        rows={data}
        rowsUniqueKey={uid}

      ></Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Table Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 250,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  chips: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2,
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));


export default function SimpleTable(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {props.columns.map(({ ...column }) => (
                <TableCell
                  align={column.align}>
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {props.rows.map((row) => (
              <TableRow key={row[props.rowsUniqueKey]}>
                {props.columns.map(({ ...column }) => (
                  <TableCell
                    component={column.component}
                    scope={column.scope}
                    align={column.align}>
                    {row[column.id]}
                  </TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Before update

[image: Before update]

After update

[image: After Update]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own question. The approach was correct but I had a mistake in getColumnDetailsFromData(data) wherein I tried to iterate through keys of "rows" instead of "data" (The variable I had passed in.) This appeared to work because I had previously specified an array rows[] which I had edited out of the code before posting the question, which the function was drawing on. Therefore the table was not receiving the correct columns, as they were based on other data.

Additionally, I had to change the code in useEffect to get the columns from the result of the API call, rather than "data", which is specified in a useState(). This is because "data" was undefined at the point getColumnDetailsFromData(data) is called. I am not sure why it is undefined, as the previous line sets the state. (Maybe the state is only set after useEffect() has finished executing?):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getDummyPlayerData("1").then(result => {
      setData(result);
      //setColDetails(getColumnDetailsFromData(data));
      setColDetails(getColumnDetailsFromData(result));
    })
  }, []);
```

Please see below for working code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Table from './SimpleTable';
import { getDummyPlayerData } from '../api_helper/api'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const getColumnDetailsFromData = (data) => {
  var columns = [];

  Object.keys(data[0]).forEach((key, index) => {
    columns.push({
      id: key,
      label: key,
      align: "right",
      component: "",
      scope: ""
    })
  })

  columns[0].align = "";
  columns[0].component = "th";
  columns[0].scope = "row";

  return columns;
}

export default function ParentDisplayTable() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [colDetails, setColDetails] = useState([]);
  const [uid, setUid] = useState(['player_id'])

  useEffect(() => {
    getDummyPlayerData("1").then(result => {
      setData(result);
      setColDetails(getColumnDetailsFromData(result));
    })
  }, []);

  const updateTable = async (event) => {
    const result = await getDummyPlayerData("2");
    setData(result);
    setColDetails(getColumnDetailsFromData(result));
  }

  return (

    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        margin="normal"
        onClick={e => updateTable(e)}
      >
        Update Table
        </Button>

      <Table
        columns={colDetails}
        rows={data}
        rowsUniqueKey={uid}
      ></Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```